# How to properly set up config files for sensitive credentials?

Tags: spring-boot, security, configuration, passwords, password-protection

I am currently developing a backend application with spring-boot which has access to a database. The login credentials for the database are stored in a file called application.properties which is just an example for spring-boot but this has to be similar to other technologies I presume.

I was wondering whether this is the state of the art to store sensitive credentials or if there is another (better, safer) way to store this kind of information? What kind of techniques exist for such challenges?

Surely you do not want to push these config files to any versioning repositories and such but is it "safe" enough to store it this way?
One could argue that if someone has access to the code of your backend application you have other problems but I am still curious.

Answer (score 0):

The argument that you use is correct. Let's say that one option is encryption. Even if you encrypt your credentials, the application will use the private key to decrypt, right? And if the server is compromised, the attacker could read the source code, find the private key and decrypt the credentials.

One way of making it more secure is using a request to collect the credentials. It could be done by an REST request (An API that could provide you the credentials to the application through a request).

And the most secure way is using a Password Vault. [This post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180243/best-practices-for-storing-credentials-used-by-code) has good content about it.